# Find and drag artwork that is outside of the artboard - Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Artwork that is outside of the artboard is not visible and draggable. 
Is there a quick way to find their position and drag them back to the art board?

Comment: What Photoshop version do you use? When I move an artwork outside the artboard it's automatically moved out of the artboard in the layer stack and made visible so I can't reproduce your problem (CC2019). Could you provide some screenshots or a sample psd?

Comment: Thanks @SergeyKritskiy latest version. once the artwork is outside of the artboard, it is not visible. I can select the layer of the artwork and move around with the Up-Right-Down-Left keys but the issue is since they can't be seen on screen(out of the artboard), I can't use the move tool to simply drag them around.